# mysql create command error

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax

i am running the following mysql command but it gave a strange error

the command is:

```
CREATE TABLE SATURN.SCBCRSE
(
  SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE             VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
  SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB             VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
  SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM              VARCHAR2(6),
  SCBCRSE_COLL_CODE             VARCHAR2(2),
  SCBCRSE_DIVS_CODE             VARCHAR2(4  )
)
TABLESPACE DEVELOPMENT
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

the error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL, SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL, ' at line 3
```

could you please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what language this is, but it's not mySQL? Edit: According to Google, it's Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the `CREATE TABLE` syntax of MySQL. I believe this is the Oracle's syntax. You may want to check the MySQL syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

Good luck!

Comment: is it possible to convert from oracle to myqsl. i.e is there any tool that do that

Comment: Yes, there is such a toolkit though I haven't used it. See more infos here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely an Oracle script you using. Oracle supports CHAR, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2 and VARCHAR2 whereas MySQL supports CHAR and VARCHAR. You can probably also remove everything from Tablespace onwards. Tablespace can be used from MySQL 5.1 onwards but it still isn't as straightforward as with Oracle.